# Move files not in use and preserve directory structure

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rsync

I'm trying to move files from a source folder that is constantly being written to (Files and Folders). Once a file is no longer being written, it won't be r/w again. I want to move the files that aren't in use to another folder, but preserving the directory structure. I will eventually want to add this into a continuous loop or have it run at regular intervals to "clean out" the source folder.

Here is my example before and after:

```
Before:
Parent/
├── Source/
│   ├── DirA/
│   │   ├── File1InUse.abc
│   │   ├── File2NotInUse.abc
│   │   └── File3InUse.abc
│   └── DirB/
│       ├── File4InUse.abc
│       ├── File5NotInUse.abc
│       └── File6NotInUse.abc
│
├── Destination/

After:
Parent/
├── Source/
│   ├── DirA/
│   │   ├── File1InUse.abc
│   │   └── File3InUse.abc
│   └── DirB/
│       └── File4InUse.abc
│
├── Destination/
    ├── DirA/   
    │   └── File2NotInUse.abc
    └── DirB/
        ├── File5NotInUse.abc
        └── File6NotInUse.abc
```

I have found [answers](https://superuser.com/questions/219564/how-to-move-files-that-are-not-in-use) to moving files that moves files that are not in use:

```
comm -2 -3 <(find $dir -maxdepth 1 -type f|sort) <(sudo lsof $dir/* | awk '(NR>1) {print $9}'|sort) | xargs -I {} mv {} $move_dir
```

I have also found [answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59112/preserve-directory-structure-when-moving-files-using-find) to moving files and preserving the directory structure:

maybe with `rsync`:

```
rsync -axuv --delete-after --progress Source/ Target/
```

I'm not that knowledgeable in command line so I'm not sure how to put these two concepts together.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can I use file permissions to check whether file is in use? As per your question, if file changes to read only from read write, it is not is use. right?

Comment: How long are files written (seconds, hours, weeks?); How short a delay do you need after they are no longer in use before they are moved?

Comment: I don't see why not for file permissions.

Files will typically be writing for hours. Move delay doesn't matter, can be hours. Days might be too long.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I will do it. A script is created so that you can use it from other programs or cron jobs.

```
#! /bin/bash

isUsed() {
    test -w "$1" && echo 1 || echo 0
}

parent_dir=$1
src_dir=$2
dst_dir=$3

while read -r line
do
    retval=$(isUsed "$line")
    if [ $retval -eq "0" ]
    then
        filepath=$(dirname $line)
        filepath=${filepath#$parent_dir}
        filepath=${filepath#$src_dir}
        mkdir -p "$parent_dir$dst_dir$filepath"
        mv "$line" "$parent_dir$dst_dir$filepath"/
    fi
done <<< $(find "$parent_dir$src_dir")
```

**Usage**

```
./script.sh Parent/ Source/ Destination/
```

**Working**

1. `isUsed` function is used to check whether a file is currently being used or not.

   Return value : `1` - file is being used, `0` - file is not being used

   Currently, the file permissions are used to find if a file is in use. If a file has write permissions, then it is considered as being used. You can change it to any other logic for evaluating if a file is used, like `lsof` as mentioned in your question.
2. `find "$parent_dir$src_dir"` will list all the files and directories in the given path. The output of `find` command is read one at a time into `$line` using the while loop.

   Example : Suppose `$line` equals `Parent/Source/DirA/File2NotInUse.abc`
3. We invoke the `isUsed` function to check if the file is being used or not. The return value of function call is stored into `$retval`
4. If `$retval` equals `"0"`, it means the file is not being used and we have to move it to the destination directory.
5. First we will generate the path of the file to be moved using `dirname`. It will return the relative path of the file.

   `$filepath` equals `Parent/Source/DirA`

   Then we remove the parent directory name from the `filepath`.

   Therefore `$filepath` becomes `Source/DirA`

   Then we remove the source directory name from `filepath`.

   Therefore `$filepath` now equals `DirA`. This resulting `filepath` will be the path of the file relative to the source directory.
6. Create a directory in `Destination/` with the given `filepath`. `mkdir -p` will create all intermediate directories as given in `filepath`.

   `mkdir -p Parent/Destination/DirA`
7. The last step is to move the actual file from its `Source` path to the newly created `Destination` path.

   `mv Parent/Source/DirA/File2NotInUse.abc Parent/Destination/DirA/`